# CSV folder always get overwritten

Tags: python, csv

My program always overwrites my existing CSV folder whenever the program runs. How can I create a CSV file that does not get overwritten?

For example: It will check the directory and if such file `TabulatedStats.csv` is found it will create a `TabulatedStats02.csv`, `TabulatedStats03.csv` and so on which is different from the original file.

This is what I tried:

```
try:
    newDirRH = 'C:\AGM'
    newfile = newDirRH + "/TabulatedStats.csv"
    text_file = open(newfile, "w")
    x = stringText
    text_file.write(x)
    text_file.close()
except:
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="New Excel Created", message="New TabulatedStats1.csv is created")
    newfile = newDirRH + "/TabulatedStats1.csv"
    text_file = open(newfile, "w")
    x = stringText
    text_file.write(x)
    text_file.close()
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a file exists with the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html) module.

```
filename = 'path/to/file{0:05}.ext'
n = 0
while os.path.exists(filename.format(n)):
    n += 1
print(filename.format(n))
```

Comment: How is that very weird? You can adjust the number of 0's by changing the `5` above. Might want to look at the [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatstrings) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file in write mode. This will always create a new file. If you open a file in append mode, you can add new content without overriding existing content.

```
text_file = open(newfile, "a")
```